# How to break AWS certificate to public/private keys and intermediate certificate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate

I've issued a wildcard certificate in AWS to install on the company's website (which is stored in a CloudFront distribution).

There's a customer support service which the company uses and when you browse to support.company.com it takes you to that service site.

Up until today, the access to the support site has been done on HTTP protocol and we would like to change it to be on HTTPS.

For that, I need to upload to that customer support service provider site the new certificate, they require Private key, Public key and Intermediate certificate.

I've run the following command to get the certificates:

```
aws iam get-server-certificate --server-certificate-name wild_company.com_10072019
```

But the output shows me the "CertificateChain" - all the certificates are display in one line and another "CertificateBody" which is also displayed in one line.

The CertificateBody is easier to distinguish by the "--- Begin certificate ---" and "---END certificate---" which appear only once but in the CertificateChain there are lots of begin/end marks and I'm not sure how to transform it to Public/Private keys and Intermediate certificate.

Any idea how can it be done?

Comment: did you upload the SSL cert or use cert manager to issue the cert?

Comment: I’ve used cert manager to issue the certificate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So when you create a certificate using AWS Cert Manager, you cannot pull out the key for the certificate chain. You can only use it for AWS services like ELB/ALB/Cloudfront

So in short, you can't pull the key out to use it in your own infrastructure like apache or nginx.